# .htaccess url rewriting - exceptions for certain files only

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1  [QSA]
```

Basically if you enter /test, it will work perfectly, and if you go to /test.php, it will show the PHP page without the rewrite rule, which is what I need for certain pages only.

let's say there are some pages (a few) where I would want this to be able (to load the whole .php page), but ALL the other pages, what I want is that if someone goes to /contact.php, it redirects to /contact, to the right one.

So let's say for "result.php" and "search.php", I want it to be able to load the whole PHP page, but for the rest, I want it to redirect to the right adress (so /contact.php => /contact).

How could I do it? Basically I need to add this RewriteRule (    `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ [NC]`) only for a few pages (that I would determine myself), and for the rest of the pages I need another RewriteCond (that redirects all the "test.php" to "test")

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can put all those exception in your first RewriteCond and alter 2nd RewriteCond to skip real files and real directories like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index|result|search)\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```